# how do I recursively find an element in a linked list but the last element is not equal to None

Tags: python, linked-list, nodes

Im trying to find the last value on a linkedlist but the last node does not does not point to none. node 4 is not pointing to none so how do I find it recursively.

```
node1 = Node(44)
node2 = Node(220)
node3 = Node(320)
node4 = Node(402)
node2.setNext(node1)
node3.setNext(node2)
node4.setNext(node3)
```

so if I put in find the last value of node4 it should return 44

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
n = node1
while n.next() == None:
    n = n.next()
 ... do something ...
```

this while loop breaks when the last node is n so you can use n to refrence last node. Hope this helps  :)

Edit: If there is no node linked to node1 then it should return None when you run node1.next also i didn't quite understood the question if you want a recursive function of getting the last node here it is.

```
def r(n: linkedlist)
    if n.next() == None:
        return n
    else:
        r(n.next())
```

Comment: node4 is the first node in the list (a little backwards to intuition). And I believe in your while loop `n = node1.next` should be `n = n.next()`

Answer (score 1):

Your linked list looks like this:

```
node4 -> node3 -> node2 -> node1
```

**No start, no end, your linked list is in a vacuum.**

Correct it to it will look like,

```
linked_list -> node4 -> node3 -> node2 -> node1 -> None
```

So, you need to add the command

```
node1.setNext(None)
```

Moreover, you need a class for creating linked lists, say `LinkedList`, which instances will have a pointer to the first member.

You may implement this class with the method for setting this pointer, say `setFirst()`; then you will use these commands:

```
my_list = LinkedList()
my_list.setFirst(node4)
```

or set this pointer directly in the constructor (i. e. in the `__init__()` method); then you will use this command:

```
my_list = LinkedList(node4)
```